# Power BI dashboard not updating automatically

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Why Power BI service does not refresh data automatically. The forums mention that with Power BI Pro license allows to schedule refresh 8 times and Power BI Premium allows us to schedule refresh with a higher frequency. There is always an option to manually refresh the dataset/dashboard.
Does that mean Power BI does not provide the ability for live reporting. 
We are not sure when was the last update for the dashboard. 
Please suggest if we have some workaround. Iam using web api as data source.

Answer (score 0):

Real-time reports are possible with [push or streaming datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming).

[DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery) is another possibility for frequently changing data.

Answer (score 0):

What's your connection ? DirectQuery or import in your current report ?

Comment: Connection is Rest API call with token for Authorisation.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule refresh for your dashboard does not mean your data will refresh, you have to refresh your dataset also, and depending your source if you are using dataflows it will refresh your last dataset update. I'll suggest you to check out guy in the cube channel on youtube.

Comment: Data source is Rest API Call.

Comment: Iam passing the token for Authorisation.